# Uploading videos from iOS app to Dropbox and Google Drive?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I am working on a project where I need to share the videos in Dropbox and Google Drive. While reviewing the APIs of these two I found that they provide file uploading. They gave an example of text file uploading. But I am not sure about Video File uploading from iOS app? Has anybody done this before? If yes then please share the example code for it or any link which helps me for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the Dropbox API at least, there isn't really any difference between uploading text files versus video files, etc. (Aside from the fact that video files are probably larger and will take longer.) That being the case, the tutorial (for whichever API you're using) should help:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios

You would just need to use the path for your video file instead of the text file from the tutorial.